# How to use google analytics Api without using google account

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

we are provide saas plugin to our customers, we need to  get events for each customer's website without creating seperate GTM container and GA property , All the process will takes place in background.
There should be no login requried ,insted we will send the username and password to Google Aalytics through code(JavaScript).

so we need to use google analytics Api without google sign in

is there a way to do this

Comment: are you connecting to your customers existing websites?

Comment: We are not connecting to customers website data, we want to track our plugin events which loads on multiple websites as iframe.

Answer (score 1):

> we are provide saas plugin to our customers, we need to get events for each customer's website

If you want to connect to the analytics accounts for your customers websites they you need to be authorized to access their private data.

> no login requried ,insted we will send the username and password to Google Aalytics through code(JavaScript).

You can not login to anyones google account using login and password that was called client login and google disabled that in 2015. You will need to use Oauth2 request consent and gain authorization to access their private data.

> so we need to use google analytics Api without google sign in

Sign in is authentication, the Google analytics api operations on authorization. The user needs to consent and grate you authorization to access their data.

> is there a way to do this

No you can not access private user data without the owner of that data authorizing your access to that data.

Comment: We are not connecting to customers website data, we want to track our plugin events which loads on multiple websites as iframe.

Comment: Then why not just load it all in to one google analytics account and have a custom dimension noting the customer whos data you are tracking.    There is no reason to create a new view for each user unless you plan on putting a filter on each profile so that it only accepts the data for that single user, in which case your going to need a custom dimension to filter on anyway.  If you do go that way you wont be able to preform any analytics across all your customers.    Are they aware your going to be tracking their usage in this manner?

Comment: yes, they are aware of it. Can you suggest some links to filter events on GA by each user/custom dimension?